# "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" when uploading an image with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm able to post an image to a rails app with no problem:

```
 curl -v include --form image=@filename.jpg https://my_url_goes_here.com/path/to/imageupload
```

...but when I try to upload with Alamofire.upload, I'm seeing the 'invalid byte sequence in UTF-8' error on the server and nothing's being saved.

'image' is a valid UIImage.

```
    let pictureData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.8)

    Alamofire.upload(.POST, "https://my_url_goes_here.com/path/to/imageupload", pictureData)
        .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
            println(totalBytesWritten)
        }
        .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
            println(JSON)
    }
}
```

Alamofire.upload is supposed to take NSData as an argument (and presumably encode it appropriately before attempting to upload), so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: Unless the image data is in Base64, it can't possibly be UTF8.

Comment: How are you specifying the MIME type?

Comment: @HotLicks both good points-- though I expected Alamofire.upload to at least automatically take care of encoding the NSData into Base64 so it can be safely uploaded. I also expected it to handle MIME types appropriately but perhaps it doesn't-- I'll dig a bit deeper. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Generally you'd upload an image using a "bulk data" protocol that did not require Base64 encoding.  How you'd specify this with Alamofire I haven't a clue.

Comment: Somehow you should be specifying "Content-Type: image/jpeg" in your HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I should have read the Alamofire docs more closely-- the file upload I was trying to do needed to be as multipart data, which [Alamofire does not yet support](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#when-should-i-use-afnetworking)... so using AFNetworking here with its built-in multipart form uploading support worked.